# Seating arrangement round table

Tags: combinatorics

Given a group of $p_1$ ladies and $p_2$ gents and a round table with exactly $p_1+p_2$ places. For reasons which I do not dare to mention, I want to find a seating arrangement such that nobody is sitting in-between two ladies.

1) Say that $p_1$=$p_2$=$p \geq 10$. For which values of $p$ it is possible to make a seating arrangement?

2) Give an expression for the number of possible seating arrangements  for those values of $p$ for which a seating arrangement is possible. In this case, a host and hostess have fixed places abreast each other and all the ladies and gents are distinguishable.

Results so far:

I know that there a no possibilities if $p_1$>$p_2$. It seems to me that a seating arrangement is possible if $p$ is odd. But I don't know if this is true.

Comment: When you write "nobody is sitting in-between two ladies" do you mean "*no gent* is sitting in-between two ladies"?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I assume he means nobody of either sex is sitting between two ladies. Otherwise the arrangement would always be possible except when $p_2=1$; just put all the ladies in consecutive places.

Comment: @bof that is true! No men of women can sit in between two ladies. So at least 2 men has to seat in between two ladies.

Comment: At least 2 men has to sit between two ladies? You mean 2 ladies can't sit next to each other? That's not how I understood the question.

Comment: @bof you are right! You can place two ladies next to each other. Excuse me for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Wasn't this question just posted here yesterday, but with red & green balls instead of women and men?

Comment: Yes! But the question was not the same. That there are no possibilities if $p_1>p_2$ is a result of yesterday's post.

Comment: Whatever --- when you post a question closely related to another one, you should link the two questions, so everyone knows what's going on. We'll let the community decide whether it's a duplicate.

Comment: Moreover, the onus is then on you to indicate clearly in the body of the new question just exactly how the new question differs from the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Define a graph $G$ as follows. The vertices are the $p$ places at the table. Two vertices are joined by an edge if there is exactly one place between them. So $G$ is a $2$2$-regular graph with $p$ vertices and $p$ edges; the task is to assign the ladies to independent (i.e. non-adjacent) vertices at the table.

If $p$ is odd, then $G$ is just a $p$-cycle; a seating arrangement is always possible if $p_1\lt\frac p2$.

If $p=10$ then $G=2C_5$ (two $5$-cycles), so a seating arrangement is possible for up to $4$ ladies, no more.

You can take it from there.